# How to populate data to GridControl from Web Service?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, bindingsource, gridcontrol

I have a problem with adding rows/cells values to GridControl.
I am using Web Service as data source.
My web service function runs perfectly and returns an xml type of value
e.g.

```
<User>
<UserID>000015</UserID>
<UserGroup>MR</UserGroup>
<UserName>ARIF SETYOWARDOYO</UserName>
<IsActive>1</IsActive>
</User>
```

I added my web service to my project as 'Add Services'.
And, my BindingSource code:

```
userBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(DXWindowsApplication1.WebService.User);
```

I have attached my BindingSource to the GridControl, and it automatically creates 4 columns, which are UserID, UserGroup, UserName, and IsActive.

but there's no data in their rows. If I run this script below, it'd run and return the values..

```
WebService.MyWebServiceWs = new WebService.MyWebServiceWs ();
WebService.User[] user = Ws.GetUserDetails();
string userId = user[0].UserID.ToString();
string userGroup = user[0].UserGroup.ToString();
string userName = user[0].UserName.ToString();
string isActive = user[0].IsActive.ToString();//int isActive = user[0].IsActive.Value;
```

so my question is, what am I to do next to get retrieve this WebService data into GridControl?

 any reference would be really appreciated...

 Thank You :)

 Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

i read xml from web without webservice,and poupolate my table with this code:

```
// needed variable
private DataSet ds;
//read xml and poupolate table
 System.Xml.XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument();

                xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("http://your link to xml");
                ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;



                datagridviwe1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
                datagridviwe1.DataMember = "User";
```

but you need some change in our xml file,this is an example:

```
<User UserID="000015" UserGroup="MR" UserName="ARIF SETYOWARDOYO" IsActive="1" />
<User UserID="000016" UserGroup="MRS" UserName="LADY LAYON" IsActive="0" />
```

This poupolate table with all value,for personalize showed content you need to bindingsource with your xsd schema and edit table generate.

Comment: Hi devilkkw, Thanks for your reply. it's really inspirating me to move forward. But, I still have problem in this situation coz I have to use webservice and I don't know how I can change that xml format.

Comment: i think for use your webservice,you need to create array for all data recived,then use it for generate datagrid(method foreach).I've not try this method,and i didn't help you with sample code.sorry.